# How do I know this critical point is the local maximum?

Tags: calculus

Let
$f(x) = 4ln(10x)-4x$, $x>0$

I found the derivative and the critical point was 1, however, how do I know whether or not this is the local maxima or minima ?

The next part of the question also asks:

1)  a.The interval on the left of the critical point is ....

b.On this interval, $f$ is.....          while $f'$ is .....

2) a.The interval on the right of the critical point is ....

b.On this interval, $f$ is.....          while $f'$ is .....

Any explanation on how to figure our 1 and 2 , along with how to determine whether the critical point is the maxima or minima would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What can you say about the sign of $f'(x)$ on each side of the critical point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking values to the left and right of $x$ and substituting it into $f(x)$. For example, if we have $f'(1)=0$, then take values such as 0.99, 0.98, and 1.01, 1.02, and investigate the "behaviour" of the graph at those points.

Alternatively, you can take use the "*Second Derivative Test*", which gives you a good idea of the behaviour of $f(x)$. Typically,

1. when $f''(x)<0$, the point is a local maximum, and,
2. when $f''(x)>0$, the point is a local minimum.

However, this is not always the case (for example, $x=0$ for $y=x^3$), so for a more foolproof method, "probe" the behaviour near the point $x=1$. You will find that it is a maximum point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

compute the second derivative at the critical point, if it is negative the critical point is a local maximum